# Usage of Web.storage in Jquery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I'm working on my webpage, because I want my jobs to be stored on page and I can check them anytime I want.

This is my code at the moment: http://jsfiddle.net/p0cdbozx/

I have already done that you can add any job you need, and you can delete it by clicking on it, also slideUp and slideDown function.

The only thing I can't figure out how to do is WEB STORAGE. I want that informations I type in table will be saved anytime I open the website.

If I am not wrong I should add something like that code:

```
localStorage.data=$("#table").html();
document.getElementById("table").innerHTML=localStorage.data;
```

but the problem is I actually don't know where exactly to put it in.

If anyone have minute of time, please check out my problem and help me!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://html5demos.com/storage

Comment: @Pinal What exactly is that website? I don't know what to put in. Sorry but I am begginer at websites :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to burst your bubble, but localStorage only supports strings.

Use JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse() to be able to set and store the data.

To set:

```
if(typeof localStorage["tableHtml"] !== 'undefined')
$('#table').html(JSON.parse(localStorage["tableHtml"]));
```

and to store:

```
localStorage["tableHtml"] = JSON.stringify($('#table').html());
```

Have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/p0cdbozx/1/